# How to announce a new web-page?

Tags: etiquette, online-resource, networking, website

Our lab has recently developed a new webpage; we are thinking of ways to announce it's creation via social media and email:

- Is there an etiquette for making such announcements?
- Perhaps there are example announcements you could share?

Comment: Does it need to be announced? Usually linking to it from your department's site and the lab members' personal sites is enough.

Comment: Is the intention of this site (in part) to inform the general public of your research initiatives?

Comment: Some social service? Beyond that, I don't know if there is a need.

Comment: And be careful not to verge into spamming...

Comment: I have removed the link, because it is not germane to this discussion.

Comment: Sorry if it seemed like advertising @aeismail the intention was to help to understand our scope of research, but fair decision

Comment: The bigger reason why it's not germane is that if you're asking where to advertise _your_ site, then your question can't help others, which makes it off-topic.

Comment: In addition to @AustinHenley's point, you might be able to get the webpage linked through a "featured" section on your department website. This will usually have an image and a short description which will be seen immediately by anybody visiting the department site.

Answer (score 8):

If there's a reason for someone to visit your lab's site other than it's new and should be visited, then you could write up a short announcement and post it to a relevant mailing list for your particular discipline or sub-discipline.

Otherwise, the best and most persistent advertising you and your groupmates can do would be to include it as a signature block in your email. People who want to know more about your group can then click on the link. Other methods to generate traffic without purpose will likely tick off more people than inspire them to visit your page.

Comment: This is for lab site. Should I add my personal site under my signature?